# Computing the limit or proving it doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Two functions i'm having a hard time to deal with. I am supposed to compute the limit or show that it doesn't exist.

1. In the first one I dont know where to begin.
2. The second one I managed to mark $x = t - π $, and continued on with opening the results with the $\cos(x+y)$ identity, which unfortunately didn't lead anywhere significant.

I would appreciate some help ! Thank you.

$$\lim_{x→1} {{x·\cos(x−1)−1}\over {x-1}}$$

$$\lim_{x→π}{{\cos({{x} \over {2}})} \over {π^2−x^2}}$$

Comment: You can use L'hospital rule for the first one.

Comment: @BrightChancellor Why not for the second too?

Comment: @HenryTuring and for the second of course :)

Comment: @MathChallenged You can choose one of the elegant answers if you want .)

Comment: Thank you so much everyone !

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate each limit using the definition of the derivative applied to the cosine function.

For the first limit, let $x-1=u$, so that

$${x\cos(x-1)-1\over x-1}={(u+1)\cos u-1\over u}=\cos u+{\cos u-1\over u}=\cos u+{\cos u-\cos0\over u-0}$$

Since $u\to0$ as $x\to1$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to1}{x\cos(x-1)-1\over x-1}=\lim_{u\to0}\cos u+\lim_{u\to0}{\cos u-\cos0\over u-0}=\cos0-\sin0=1$$

where we get $-\sin0$ as the derivative of the cosine function at $u=0$.

Similarly, for the second limit, let ${x\over2}=u$, so that

$${\cos({x\over2})\over\pi^2-x^2}={\cos u\over\pi^2-(2u)^2}={(\pi+2u)}{\cos u\over2({\pi\over2}-u)}={-1\over2(\pi+2u)}{\cos u-\cos({\pi\over2})\over u-{\pi\over2}}$$

In this case $u\to{\pi\over2}$ as $x\to\pi$, so

$$\lim_{x\to\pi}{\cos({x\over2})\over\pi^2-x^2}=\left(\lim_{u\to{\pi/2}}{-1\over2(\pi+2u)}\right)\left(\lim_{u\to\pi/2}{\cos u-\cos({\pi\over2})\over u-{\pi\over2}}\right)=\left(-1\over4\pi\right)\left(-\sin\left({\pi\over2}\right)\right)={1\over4\pi}$$

where this time we get $-\sin\left({\pi\over2}\right)$ as the derivative of the cosine function at $u={\pi\over2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Hôpital rule? Basically when you meet a form like

$$\frac{0}{0}$$

or

$$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

You can prove that

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Example: you first function has the form $0/0$ if you substitute.

Use Hôpital rule and you get

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\cos(x-1) - x\sin(x-1)}{1} = \cos(0) - \sin(0) = 1$$

You can do the second one in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try Taylor series:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{x\cos(x-1)-1}{x-1}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{(x-1)\cos(x-1)+\cos(x-1)-1}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{(x-1)\left(1-\dfrac{(x-1)^{2}}{2!}+\cdots\right)+1-\dfrac{(x-1)^{2}}{2!}+\cdots-1}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\left(1-\dfrac{(x-1)^{2}}{2!}+\cdots-\dfrac{x-1}{2!}+\cdots\right)\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

For the first, note that for $x\approx 1$, 
$$
\cos(x-1)=1-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+O((x-1)^4)
$$
making your first limit 
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-x\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}-1+O((x-1)^4)}{x-1}=
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(x-1)(1-x\frac{(x-1)}{2}+O((x-1)^3))}{x-1}=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

1) $$\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{(t+1)\cos t -1}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\cos t + \dfrac{\cos t -1}{t} = 1+\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{-\sin^2(t/2)}{t}= 1$$

2)

$$\dfrac1{2\pi}\lim_{x→π}{\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) \over {π−x}} = \dfrac1{2\pi}\lim_{t \to 0}{\cos\left(\dfrac t2 +\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right) \over {-t}}= \dfrac1{4\pi}\lim_{t \to 0}{\sin\left(\dfrac t2\right) \over {t/2}} = \dfrac1{4\pi}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write the first function as

$$\frac {(x-1)\cos (x-1)-(1-\cos (x-1))}{x-1} $$

and use

$$\lim_1\frac {1-\cos(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}=\frac {1}{2} $$

**You will find $1$.**

For the second,  use

$$\cos (x/2)=\sin (\pi/2-x/2) $$

and
$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac {\sin(\pi/2-x/2)}{\pi/2-x/2}=1$$

**You will get $\frac {1}{4\pi }$.**

Comment: @123 recompute it again.

Answer (score 0):

By the change of variable $x-1=t$,

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x\cos(x-1)-1}{x-1}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(t+1)\cos t-1}t=1+\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\cos t-\cos 0}t=1+\cos'(0).$$

And by the change of variable $x\to\pi-2t$, and factoring $\pi^2-x^2$,

$$\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\cos\frac x2}{\pi^2-x^2}=\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac1{x+\pi}\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t-\sin 0}{2t}=\frac{\sin'(0)}{4\pi}.$$